# Using camera on Raspberry Pi 3 running ROS::Kinetic

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all.

Could somebody please point me in the right direction to where I can find instructions on how I can get the pi's camera to work with ROS:Kinetic. I'm struggling to find how to get this to work

---

Edit:  I've just started using ROS and I want to start play around using it with cameras and lidar sensors. I've seen a lot of interesting projects using ROS and cameras, hence I want to use ROS with my raspberry pi. Is there a way to tap into the camera feed using a separate program and send the feeds to a ROS node for processing?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/250685/using-camera-on-raspberry-pi-3-running-ros::kinetic/) by [Nasher128](https://answers.ros.org/users/28885/nasher128/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-12-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-12-23**:
First things first: can you use the camera with any 'regular' (as far as ROS is non-regular) Linux programs? If not, putting ROS in the mix isn't going to be productive, so please figure that out first.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-12-24**:
I'm suggesting to first get the camera work *without* ROS involved at all. If you can't do that, it doesn't help to complicate things by introducing nodes and drivers.

If you can use the camera (say with `guvcview`), then we can suggest how you could proceed.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-01-15**:
Not sure you're still interested in this, but at [UbiquityRobotics/raspicam_node](https://github.com/UbiquityRobotics/raspicam_node) looks related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Well you could use the Raspberry Pi Camera node that is found here:

https://github.com/UbiquityRobotics/raspicam_node

Or if you want to make life really easy for yourself you could just download a raspberry pi image that has the camera node, and all the drivers, and ROS already set up. That's available from here:

https://downloads.ubiquityrobotics.com

as always please report any bugs, issues or feature enhancements ideas at github.com/UbiquityRobotics. PRs with enhancements are particularly welcome and a friendly email to contact@ubiquityrobotics.com is always nice if something that our little project produced is useful for you.

---

Originally posted by [DrDave](https://answers.ros.org/users/33256/drdave/) with karma: 26 on 2018-01-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I use the Raspberry PI camera with ROS kinetic and Ubuntu Mate. First, download raspi-config to enable the camera. I used these directions:

https://larrylisky.com/2016/11/24/enabling-raspberry-pi-camera-v2-under-ubuntu-mate/

Next, download the usb_cam package:

sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-usb-cam

Finally, launch the usb_cam

roslaunch usb_cam usb_cam-test.launch

If you PI is not connected to a display and your are using SSH you can use the web_video_server package to view the image in your web browser.

---

Originally posted by [dpoiesz](https://answers.ros.org/users/33274/dpoiesz/) with karma: 43 on 2018-01-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rutujaharidas](https://answers.ros.org/users/44034/rutujaharidas/) on 2019-09-10**:
Hi,
I have Logitech camera with Raspberry pi 3 B ,Ubuntu Mate OS.
I tried it to connect it with ros package usb_cam and command rosrun usb_cam usb_cam_node.
And through ssh I tried it to view through rqt_image_view.
But it is showing video device busy and it terminates the node.
So what shall I do to resolve this issue.

Thanks &Regards,
Rutuja